# Generic array with Polymorphism

Tags: java, generics

I have created a base interface which is implemented by some objects and I also have an array of interfaces which given a string return the objects mentioned. (a bit difficult to explain, better look the code :D) Then I want to pass this to the global object through some overloaded methods (at the beginning looked super clever, but it now seems technically impossible) Could I get any closer to what I want?

```
interface Stats { }

public class ObjectA implements Subscriber.Stats { // MORE THINGS }

public class ObjectB implements Subscriber.Stats { // MORE THINGS }

// MORE OBJECTS
```

This is the second interface which transforms a String into one of the classes from above

```
public interface Parser<T extends Stats> {

    T parse(String data);

}
```

Now I have an array of implementations of the this interface I want to give me different results (ObjectA, ObjectB, ObjectC ..)

```
private final Parser<Stats>[] parsers = new Parser[] {
        new Parser() {
            @Override
            public Stats parse(String data) {
                return new ObjectA();
            }
        },
        new Parser() {
            @Override
            public Stats parse(String data) {
                return new ObjectB();
            }
        }
};
```

Now comes the "clever" part where I want to make something that may not be possible.

If I loop the array of *parsers* and each position gives me ObjectA, ObjectB due to Polymorphism I could call an overloaded method of a class with a signature like `push(ObjectA)` `push(ObjectB)`, right??... **Well this obviously doesn't work but is there any strategies I could use to accomplish this?**

The loop would be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < operations.length; i++) {               
    dataHolder.push(parsers[i].parse(operations[i].getResult()));
}
```

**EDITED** 
The problem is the method `T parse (String value)` is treated as if it returns `Stats` and not `T extends Stats` therefore when I call `push` it says there is no `push(Stats)` method

Comment: Are you possibly wondering about using `Class<T>.class` as a parameter to bind the generic `T` to the class you want?

Comment: this part is a bit unclear what you are asking: " I loop the array of parsers and each position gives me ObjectA, ObjectB due to Polymorphism I could call an overloaded method of a class "

Comment: +1 to @PatrickParker, can you add an example of desired loop? Is it like `for(Parser parser: parsers) consumer.consume(parser.parse(data));` when `consumer` has `consume(ObjectA a)` and `consume(ObjectB b)`?

Comment: That won't work. Your parsers have the return type of `Stats`. That won't match either of your example `consume()` methods. It's not really possible to do what you're trying here. If you had `Parser<ObjectA>` and `Parser<ObjectB>`, then you could call `consume(pa.parse(foo))`, but with the array it's not possible. Perhaps this calls for some kind of visitor pattern or similar. With just generics it won't really work.

Comment: @Kayaman Oh, interesting I'll take a look at this but could you please point me where to look or what, exactly?

Comment: @Nikolay that is exactly what I want to achieve, added more info to the question

Comment: Well your root problem seems to be that you want to call a list of parsers and pass the results automatically to different consume methods depending on the return type. Generics won't help because they would need to specify the correct parameter type. As I said in my last comment, this is possible if you explicitly specify the type, but not with an array of `Stats` typed parsers. A low cost (and ugly) solution would be to just call a single `consume()` method, and use `instanceof` there to determine which specific `consume()` method to forward it to.

Comment: @Kayaman I see, mm I guess I could live with that, but going back to what you said earlier you think this could be solved with visitor pattern?

Comment: Possibly. If you pass the `consumer` to all the `processors`, they can call the correct overloaded method inside `parse()`, since the type is known there. However the actual design would depend on a lot of things.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178480/discussion-between-iroyo-and-kayaman).

Answer (score 0):

If I got it correctly, your dataHolder interface looks like this:

```
public interface DataHolder {
    void push(ObjectA a);
    void push(ObjectB b);
}
```

In that case really your loop cannot benefit from the overloaded methods, because at cimpile time, it only knows about parsers of `Stats`.

To achieve your goal you need to use the visitor pattern, and update your `Stats` hierarchy like this:

```
public interface Stats {
    void accept(DataHolder holder);
}

public class ObjectA implements Stats {
    void accept(DataHolder holder) {
        holder.push(this); // this is ObjectA, so push(ObjectA) is used
    }
}

public class ObjectB implements Stats {
    void accept(DataHolder holder) {
        holder.push(this); // this is ObjectB, so push(ObjectB) is used
    }
}
```

Now if you do:

```
new Parser<Stat>().parse(input).accept(dataHandler);
```

It will use the propper overloaded push method (I didn't rewrite your loop, because I'm not sure if I unerstadt it properly, bu hopefully you can apply it yourself).

Answer (score -2):

Sounds reasonable to me. Just try it.

```
String dataToParse = "wklhbglbwbgiwegbuwegbwe";

for(Parser p : parsers){

    //The definition of each parser will be called and everything works.
    System.out.println(p.parse(dataToParse));
}
```

Also you can just:

```
public void push(Object obj){
    System.out.println(obj.getClass().getCardionalName());
    //Or anything else you want to do with it.
}
```